# Magento2.3: How to integrate Salesforce?

Tags: magento2.3, api, sales, magento2-enterprise

I have to integrate **Salesforce** in Magento. Since I'm new for this, I'm not sure where to start.

In order to integrate this, do we need any extension or can I integrate it without extension ?

Also, is there any helpful links for **Salesforce** integration without using any extension ?

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In order to integrate **Salesforce CRM** in Magento 2 you need to buy an extention, I thing there is a trial for this, for more detail please refer to these link.

[How to integrate salesforce with Magento 2](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-integrate-salesforce-with-magento-2.html)

[Marketplace link for extension](https://store.magenest.com/magento-2/salesforce-crm-integration.html)

[Integrate Salesforce with Magento 2 use Webhook](https://www.mageplaza.com/faqs/how-to-integrate-salesforce-with-Magento-2.html)

[Salesforce Integration by PowerSync](https://marketplace.magento.com/tnw-salesforce-basic.html#product.info.details.support)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Is it possible without third party extension?

Comment: My requirement is to collect and send customers data like wishlist, customer address to another server using SFTP. Can you please guide me on this?

Comment: I didn't know about that but I found out that, Mageplaza develops Webhook extension which allows Salesforce integrates with Magento 2 easily. I've updated my answer with additional link.

Comment: Answer updated with link of free extension to connect Magneto 2 with Salesforce. You can also go for paid version to get more features as written in extension description.

Answer (score 0):

We're a luxury wholesale company who work with leading fashion retailers and are currently looking to integrate Magento and Salesforce. We've hired developers for Magento and Salesforce who are currently working together to explore different options.

A two-way sync for creating new accounts/leads/editing customer data/listing new products are all essential features to us.

Currently we're looking at Zapier and other plugins such as Powersync and Firebear Studio.

Does anyone here have any experience with any of these extensions?

Many Thanks,

Michelle